# How to create a new nested property in an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I create an object by doing `let obj = {}`, I can create a new `link` property by doing `obj.link = 'test'` and it works.

What if I want instead to create a nested property?

The code below gives an `undefined` error:

```
let obj = {}
obj.link.link = 'test'
console.log(obj.link.link)
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: `obj.link = {link: 'test'}`

Comment: Best one I think, can you make an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access link property inside link, which is not there by the time. So you can do below things.

```js
obj = {}
obj.link = {};
obj.link.link = 'test';
console.log(obj.link.link);
console.log(obj);
```

Or

```js
 obj = {}
 obj.link = {link: 'test'}
 console.log(obj.link.link);
 console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an object to address a property inside of an object.

Toassign use a default object and assign with the value to the last property.

```js
let obj = {};

(obj.link ??= {}).link = 'test';

console.log(obj.link.link);
console.log(obj);
```